# Are questions about algorithm implementation on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I just joined the beta and I was going to post this question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212117/performance-of-a-fuzzy-jaccard-index-implementation

But I thought it might be totally out of topic based on the other sets of questions I saw in the main board. Is okay to post questions about specific implementations of a IR algorithm, for example, and asking for guidance in making they perform better?

Answer (score 4):

A question about code performance might not be specific to machine learning or data science, and so might be best suited to StackOverflow. But if the question's answer likely involves tuning or modifying the algorithm, I think it's a good fit for the specialist crowd here. I guess it depends on whether you think it's a matter of tuning code or algorithm.